# Error while importing math from functools in python

Tags: python

`ImportError: cannot import name 'GenericAlias' from 'types'`

This is the error are coming while writing and running the following code.

```
from functools import reduce

list2 =[12,235,56,76,554,75]

red = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,list2)

print(red)
```

complete error list

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "g:\VS code notes of python\Datatypes.py\practice.py", line 302, in <module>
    from functools import reduce
  File "C:\Users\grewa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import GenericAlias
ImportError: cannot import name 'GenericAlias' from 'types' (g:\VS code notes of python\Datatypes.py\types.py)
```

Comment: What version of `python` are you using?

Comment: You probably want to use `sum(list2)` instead.

Comment: please add full error message

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python3.10. The error is likely to come from some other code. Or you may have a local `functools.py` file anywhere...

Comment: python version is 3.9.6

Comment: You created the file `types.py` with the same name as a built-in module. Now Python tries to use `GenericAlias` from your file. That's not what you want. Rename your file.